# Auto-backup of SPSS

Tags: backup, spss

Does SPSS automatically create a backup of data files?

I require that because the data that was entered for a long time in SPSS was not saved, even with using Ctrl+S for many times during data entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you created your data by running DATA LIST with inline data, you could find this in the journal file, which is on by default.  However, if the data were entered in the Data Editor but not saved - I can't guess how that could happen - there would be no backup.

Comment: Where is the journal file located?

Answer (score 1):

SPSS does not auto-save as far as I know - but on my machine the `Ctrl` + `s` shortcut works to save. When you do save SPSS sends a `SAVE` command to the output window so you can always check that a save did actually occur. And if you check the output it will say if there is another type of error when trying to save the file (e.g. don't have write permissions, file is locked, etc.)

It might be worth a look to open up your journal file. If you accidentally saved the file to an unknown location it would show the directory in the journal.

Answer (score 0):

([Reference# 1479525](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21479525)) says the **auto save enhancement request** has been forwarded to SPSS Development. That was in 2011.

JKP suggested checking your journal files if the data was created by running DATA LIST with inline data (and not with the Data Editor).
To figure out the **location of your journal files** open SPSS, then go to 'Edit' > 'Options' > 'File Locations'.

I also had problems with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> during my last data entry that occured in two different situations:

1. The data set wasn't activated. Window title bar showed [ ] instead of [DataSet1]. On Crtl+S the output window then displayed an error. 'Save as' worked without problems.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> after every completed case, no problems. Then sometimes instead of saving, it simply activated the cell or nothing happened at all. Only restarting SPSS made <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> work again. I never figured out the cause, it didn't seem to be linked to any specific action. 
   Perhaps SPSS 20 doesn't play well with Ubuntu 12.04. Again, 'Save as' was reliable.